# Trying to reverse the digits in the rows only in a 2d array, giving me errors and don't think i did i correctly

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, reverse

What i am trying to do it reverse only the digits in each row, so the columns for row[0] would be reversed etc. i figured out how to do them both looking online but cant figure out how to do what i need it to do. additionally its giving me a null error and i can't figure out why that's happening, my entire code is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Proj5 {
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] quizKey = {1,1,2,2,1,1,3,2,4,1,3,5,4,1,2};
    String [] userAnswers = new String[100];
    String [] wid = new String[100];
    int [][] userIndividualAnswers = new int[quizKey.length][userAnswers.length];
    int [] numCorrect = new int[quizKey.length];
    int max;
    int min;

    int lines=0;
    readInText();
    s = readInText();
    while(s.hasNext()){
        String line = s.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(",");
        wid[lines] = tokens[0];
        userAnswers[lines] = tokens[1];
        lines ++;

    }// end while loop
    Long[][] userAnswersInt = new Long[lines][quizKey.length];
    numCorrect = gradeSingleQuiz(lines, quizKey, userAnswers, numCorrect, userAnswersInt);
    double[] percentCorrect = new double[lines];
    percentCorrect = percentCorrect(lines, numCorrect, quizKey);
    char[] grades = new char[lines];
    grades = grade(numCorrect, lines);
    max=max(numCorrect);
    min=min(numCorrect);

    displayOutput(wid, lines, numCorrect, grades, percentCorrect);
    averageScore(max, min, lines, percentCorrect);
}//end main

public static Scanner readInText()throws IOException{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("QuizScores.txt"));
    return inFile;


}// end readInText

public static String[] userAnswers(String userAnswers[]){
    return userAnswers;
}

public static int[] gradeSingleQuiz(int lines, int quizKey[], String userAnswers[], int numCorrect[], Long userAnswersInt[][]){
    for (int j=0; j<lines; j++){
    numCorrect[j]=0;
        long[] ara = new long[quizKey.length];
        ara [j] = Long.parseLong(userAnswers[j]);
        for(int p=0; p<ara.length; p++){
            System.out.println(p);
            userAnswersInt[j][p]=ara[j]%10;
            ara[j]=ara[j]/10;
        }
        int rows = userAnswersInt.length;
        int cols = userAnswersInt[0].length;
        long[][] userAnswersReverse = new long[rows][cols];
        for(int q=rows-1; q>=0;q--){
            for(int w = cols-1; w >=0; w++){
                userAnswersReverse[rows-1-q][cols-1-q] = userAnswersInt[q][w];

System.out.print(userAnswersReverse[q][w]);
            }
        }
        for(int n=0; n<quizKey.length; n++){
            System.out.println(userAnswersInt[j][n]);
            if(userAnswersInt[j][n].equals(quizKey[n])){
                    numCorrect[j]++;    
            }
        }
    }//end for loop

return numCorrect;
}// end gradeSingleQuiz

public static int max(int numCorrect[]){
    int max = numCorrect[0];
    for(int r=1; r<numCorrect.length; r++){
        if(numCorrect[r]>max){

max=numCorrect[r];
        }
    }
return max;
}

public static int min(int numCorrect[]){
    int min = numCorrect[0];
    for(int r=1; r<numCorrect.length; r++){
        if(numCorrect[r]<min){
            min=numCorrect[r];
        }
    }

return min;
}

public static char[] grade(int numCorrect[], int lines){
    char[] grade = new char[lines];
    for (int j=0; j<lines; j++){

        if(numCorrect[j]>=14)
            grade[j]='A';
        else if((numCorrect[j]>=12)&&(numCorrect[j]<14))
            grade[j]='B';
        else if((numCorrect[j]>=11)&&(numCorrect[j]<12))

grade[j]='C';
        else if ((numCorrect[j]>=9)&&(numCorrect[j]<11))
            grade[j]='D';
        else
            grade[j]='F';
    }
    return grade;
}//end grade

public static double[] percentCorrect(int lines, int numCorrect[], int quizKey[]){
    double[] centCorrect = new double[100];
    for (int j=0; j<=lines; j++){
    centCorrect[j] = numCorrect[j]/quizKey.length;
    }
return centCorrect;
}

public static void averageScore(int min, int max, int lines, double percentCorrect[]){
    double add=0;
    for(int d=0; d<=lines; d++){    
        add = percentCorrect[d] + add;
    }//end for loop
    System.out.println("Average: " + add + "%");
    System.out.println("High Score: " + max);
    System.out.println("Low Score: " + min);
}// end averageScore

public static void displayOutput(String wid[], int lines, int numCorrect[], char grades[], double percentCorrect[]){
    System.out.println("Student ID    # Correct    %Correct    Grade");

for(int i=0; i<lines; i++){
        System.out.println("  " + wid[i] + "          " + numCorrect[i] + "          " +
                (percentCorrect[i]) + "%" + "       " + grades[i]); 
    }

}// end display output

}//end class
```

where my focus is is:

```
public static int[] gradeSingleQuiz(int lines, int quizKey[], String userAnswers[], int numCorrect[], Long userAnswersInt[][]){
    for (int j=0; j<lines; j++){
    numCorrect[j]=0;
        long[] ara = new long[quizKey.length];
        ara [j] = Long.parseLong(userAnswers[j]);
        for(int p=0; p<ara.length; p++){
            System.out.println(p);

userAnswersInt[j][p]=ara[j]%10;
            ara[j]=ara[j]/10;
        }
        int rows = userAnswersInt.length;
        int cols = userAnswersInt[0].length;
        long[][] userAnswersReverse = new long[rows][cols];
        for(int q=rows-1; q>=0;q--){
            for(int w = cols-1; w >=0; w++){
                userAnswersReverse[rows-1-q][cols-1-q] = userAnswersInt[q][w];
                System.out.print(userAnswersReverse[q][w]);
            }
        }
        for(int n=0; n<quizKey.length; n++){
            System.out.println(userAnswersInt[j][n]);
            if(userAnswersReverse[j][n]==(quizKey[n])){
                    numCorrect[j]++;    
            }
        }
    }//end for loop

return numCorrect;
}// end gradeSingleQuiz
```

The errors it is giving me are: (I am using eclipse)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Proj5.gradeSingleQuiz(Proj5.java:65)
at Proj5.main(Proj5.java:27)
```

And line 65 is:

```
userAnswersReverse[rows-1-q][cols-1-q] = userAnswersInt[q][w];
```

Hopefully this is enough information for you guys to help me and Thanks in advance, if i need to include anything else just let me know.

EDIT:

```
public static int[] gradeSingleQuiz(int lines, int quizKey[], String userAnswers[], int numCorrect[], Long userAnswersInt[][]){
    for (int j=0; j<lines; j++){
    numCorrect[j]=0;
        long[] ara = new long[quizKey.length];
        ara [j] = Long.parseLong(userAnswers[j]);
        for(int p=0; p<ara.length; p++){
            System.out.println(p);
            userAnswersInt[j][p]=ara[j]%10;
            ara[j]=ara[j]/10;
        }
        int rows = userAnswersInt.length;
            int cols = userAnswersInt[0].length;
            long[][] userAnswersReverse = new long[rows][cols];
        if(j==4){
            for(int q=0; q<userAnswersInt.length;q++){
            for(int w = cols-1; w >=0; w--){
                userAnswersReverse[q][cols-1-w] = userAnswersInt[q][w];
                System.out.print(userAnswersReverse[q][w]);
                }
            }
        }

if(j==4){
            for(int r=0; r<lines; r++){
                for(int n=0; n<quizKey.length; n++){
                    System.out.println(userAnswersReverse[r][n]);
                    if(userAnswersReverse[r][n]==(quizKey[n])){
                    numCorrect[r]++;    

}
                }
            }
        }   
    }//end for loop

return numCorrect;
}// end gradeSingleQuiz
```

Problem now is my values aren't getting returned correctly any idea why? This is what i am getting now:

```
Student ID    # Correct    %Correct    Grade
 4563123          15          1.0%       A
 2312311          9          0.0%       D
 2312345          13          0.0%       B
 5527687          9          0.0%       D
 7867567          6          0.0%       F
Average: 1.0%
High Score: 0
Low Score: 15
```

The file im pulling from is:

```
4563123,112211324135412
2312311,222121324135211
2312345,112211324135421
5527687,212111313124412
7867567,111111111111111
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors here.

The one that is causing the NullPointerException is that you are creating an array of type Long[][]. The entries here will be null by default. If it were "long[][]" -- small 'l' -- they would be 0. This wouldn't cause any exceptions, but it might still not be doing what you want.

Some entries in your array get initialized on line 6-11 of your function, but only on the first row, and then you use one of the uninitialized null values on the line that's causing the problem.

Perhaps the looping structure meant to be different, so that the code on line 6-11 gets applied to all rows and all columns before you begin reversing?

Some other things you might want to consider:

```
userAnswersReverse[rows-1-q][cols-1-q] = userAnswersInt[q][w];
```

You probably want to use "w" and not "q" for the column indexing here on both sides of the assignment.

Also, shouldn't the indices for the row be the same on both sides, given that you're trying to reverse values *within* a row, not swap the order of rows?

Another problematic line:

```
for(int w = cols-1; w >=0; w++){
```

It seems like you're counting up instead of down here.

Comment: Thank you, i think i fixed a lot of it, Ill post what i changed in an edit in a moment, but what exactly would you suggest i do in regards to the long situation, i need it to be long because of the length of the original string of numbers

Comment: The issue isn't with long, it's with the kind of subtle difference between "Long" and "long". "Long" is an object type -- you can set it to "null" (and then your program will crash if you try to calculate with it). "long" is a primitive type -- you can't set it to "null" (so you won't get a NullPointerException), but you can of course set it to the wrong values. ("Long" is actually kind of a wrapper for "long", because there are good reasons you sometimes want an object type.) The issue in your program is simply that you must be careful to initialize values before you use them.

Comment: ahh okay i get what you are saying i will change every Long to long also i added my updated code, its extremely close to working i think, its just not quite there, do you have any suggestions